# Trying to create a binary variable using where statement

Tags: sas

```
NGI IF  RAMN    LASG    LASD    RFA1    RFA2    Order   Money
2001    6   52  15  200505  1   6   1   9.07
2002    1   23  23  200509  1   6   1   23.29
2003    8   99  16  200505  1   6   1   12.41
2004    20  100 5   200511  4   4   1   5.27
2005    11  114 10  200603  3   6   1   10.63
2006    9   138 20  200512  1   6   1   15.40
```

Need to create a binary variable for money, if `money < 20` then 0 otherwise 1 using where statement. Did that using if, but where keeps giving me 0 obs error.

Comment: use : `data t; set your_set; bool=money < 20; run;` . In this case you create new column with data. the where statment exist to extract data by condition from source (dataset)

Comment: What do name you want the new variable to have?

Comment: Please remember to show your code, especially when you say something isn't working. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

The `where` statement is just used to subset the data coming into the step.  You cannot use it to generate an assignment statement like you could with an IF/THEN statement.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  if money < 20 then newvar=0; 
  else newvar=1;
run;
```

Note that SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 0 (false) or 1 (true) so you could just use an assignment statement and skip the IF.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  newvar = money >= 20;
run;
```